# Timer - How do I show 2 digits?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, timer

How do I make the timer text show 00:04 instead of 0:4? I tried Google but nothing worked for me. Thanks!

```
Timer.text = string.Format("Time Survived: {0:00}:{1:00}", Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time / 60).ToString(), Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time % 60).ToString());
```

Comment: You should remove the two calls to `.ToString()`.

Comment: as @41686d6564standsw.Palestine already said: if you use `ToString` it already uses he default format so e.g. `4` -> `4` and then inserts this into your string format ... I would recommend interpolation instead `Timer.text = $"Time Survived: {Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time / 60f):00}:{Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time % 60f):00}";`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "ToString()" method inside the string.Format(), you are passing a string to the formatter instead of a number, so it won't work.

You can change it to one of the options below in order to get it working:

```
//Option 1
Timer.text = string.Format("Time Survived: {0:00}:{1:00}", Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time / 60f), Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time % 60));

//Option 2
Timer.text = $"Time Survived: {Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time / 60f):00}:{Mathf.FloorToInt(Health.time % 60):00}";
```

Both of them do the same thing.